# Class load error in freeswitch

Tags: java, classloader, freeswitch

After loading `mod_java.so`, I am getting exception as `class not found in org.freeswitch.Launcher`

Getting the below exception on freeswitch console..I have set the librarypath, classpath and some necessary arguments in `java.conf.xml`.

```
Exception in thread "Thread-7" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org/freeswitch/Launcher.class
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
    at org.freeswitch.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:65)
```

Main thing I am using `JavaSession` class of swig package to do dtmf recognition..

Please anyone tell me the solution.

Comment: Can anyone tell us the solution for this...

Answer (score 0):

In you java.conf.xml remove or comment out any startup or shutdown class.
Shutdown any running instance of freeswitch and run it again. Mod_java will load perfectly this time.